# Python tkinter. Как сделать radiobutton неактивной. Программа светофор

Tags: python, tkinter, radiobutton

Есть программа светофор, с радиокнопками переключения цветов и с пультом, который должен отключать эти кнопки, то есть кнопки, которые переключают цвета на светофоре, должны стать неактивными, и при нажатии на кнопку пульта ещё раз, они вновь должны стать активными.
Я пробовал сделать это, но у меня отключается только последняя радиокнопка, сами кнопки создаются в цикле.
Вот код:

```
# ФУНКЦИЯ ДЛЯ ПЕРЕКЛЮЧЕНИЯ ЦВЕТОВ СВЕТОФОРА
    def traffic_lighter(color=None):
        for clr in range(3):
            canvas = tk.Canvas(traffic, width=80, height=80, highlightthickness=1)
            fill_color = colors[clr] if color == colors[clr] else None
            traffic_lighter_color = colors[clr]
            canvas.create_oval(1, 1, 79, 79, fill=fill_color, outline="Black", tag="ovals")
            canvas.grid(row=clr, column=4)
            canvas.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event, param={"color": traffic_lighter_color,
                                                           "cur_color": fill_color,
                                                           }: _popmenu(event, param))

    traffic_lighter()

    # Radiobutton Callback
    def radCall():
        radSel = radVar.get()
        if radSel == 0:
            traffic_lighter("Red")
        elif radSel == 1:
            traffic_lighter("Yellow")
        elif radSel == 2:
            traffic_lighter("Green")

    # create three Radiobuttons using one variable
    radVar = tk.IntVar()

    # Next we are selecting a non-existing index value for radVar
    radVar.set(99)

    # Now we are creating all three Radiobutton widgets within one loop
    for col in range(3):
        curRad = tk.Radiobutton(traffic, text=colors[col], variable=radVar,
                                value=col, command=radCall)
        curRad.grid(column=col, row=1, sticky=tk.W)  # row=6

    # Creating three checkbuttons, САМ ПУЛЬТ
    chVar = tk.IntVar()
    check1 = tk.Checkbutton(remove_control, text="Вкл.", variable=chVar)
    check1.select()
    check1.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=tk.W)

    # GUI Callback function

    # ЭТО МОЯ ПОПЫТКА СДЕЛАТЬ КНОПКИ НЕАКТИВНЫМИ
    def checkCallback(*ignoredArgs):
        # only enable one checkbutton
        if chVar.get():
            curRad['state']='disabled'

            pass
        else:


            pass

    chVar.trace('w', lambda unused0, unused1, unused2: checkCallback())
```

Вот как выглядит окно программы: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю проблема в этом

```
curRad = tk.Radiobutton(traffic, text=colors[col], variable=radVar,
                                value=col, command=radCall)
```

Исходя из того что я вижу у вас в каждом проходе цикла перезаписывается значение curRad
и получается что на последнем проходе в этой переменной хранится ссылка на объект последнего радиобаттона

можно объявить список `curRad = []`
потом в цикле его заполнить кнопками

```
for col in range(3):
  curRad.append(tk.Radiobutton(traffic, text=colors[col], variable=radVar,
                                value=col, command=radCall))
```

Далее

```
curRad['state']='disabled'
```

заменить на

```
for i in range(3):
 curRad[i]['state']='disabled'
```

я не знаю можно ли так в Пайтоне поэтому как альтернатива:

```
for i in range(3):
 curRad[i].config(state="disabled")
```

Ну или обойтись без циклов сделав просто отдельно три переменные

```
r1 = tk.Radiobutton(аргументы)
r2..
r3..
```

Comment: Аа, а не подскажете, как исправить это можно, чтобы нормально всё было?

Comment: @Vova Иправил свой пост, теперь точно все работает

Comment: Всё, сделал, спасибо огромное!